# Upgrade Debian: advisable or necessary?

Tags: debian, upgrade

I'm using Debian 7.0. I'm not sure about the advantages in upgrade to Debian 8.0. So, what to do? Upgrade it or not?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you consider yourself as a newbie, I don't think you do mind about sysvinit and systemd, or GNOME Fallback - what are Debian Wheezy 'key features', so yes, upgrading is highly recommended, for a more secure and stable system.

Comment: Why do you think Debian 7 is not as stable and secure as Debian 8?

Comment: - For the stability: Lots bugs got fixed in Jessie, and the Debian team always keep their distro ASAP (as stable as possible, lol), so Jessie shouldn't (at least in concept) be more unstable compare to the previous version.
- For the security: New software always have security bugs fixed, and many system-related packages in Wheezy won't never be updated.  So, Jodka, I guess upgrading is more likely to be a necessity than an advice.

Comment: The Stephen Kitt's comment have got 4 clicks as "useful", while your comment, @McSinyx, have got 1 "not useful" click. Looks to me that your answer makes more sense, but by now, as a newbie, I'll still a little bit confuse with those evaluations. I hope get more feedbacks.

Comment: Oh hi Lopez, if you get confused, just install Jessie on a flash drive (like how you installed on you HDD) and try using it for, let's say a week. Since flash drive is cheap (where I'm from, you can't get one with only $3.5), it wouldn't be a problem for you to do this.

Answer (score 4):

Debian 8 includes major upgrades to pretty much all the software included in the distribution; major changes include the switch to systemd by default and much better support for UEFI systems. You'll find details in the [release announcement](https://www.debian.org/News/2015/20150426).

Staying on Debian 7 is safe for now, because it is still fully supported. (As standard until February 2016, then on [LTS](https://wiki.debian.org/LTS) until May 2018.)

So it's really up to you: if you're happy with your Debian 7 system, you can keep using it; but if you'd like any of the new features in software upgraded in Debian 8, it's easy to upgrade.

Actually, come to think of it: since you're new to GNU/Linux, there is one compelling argument in favour of upgrading to Debian 8. On Debian 8 you'll acquire systemd-based system administration reflexes, which are transferrable to other Linux-based distributions now; whereas on Debian 7 you'd learn "old-style" commands, which while still relevant, will be less relevant as time goes on (assuming systemd is here to stay).